# How can I debug FallbackResource problems in Apache?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to use FallbackResource in Apache and it isn't working, and I can't figure out how to debug the issue. I want to know 1) if Apache is hitting the directive, and 2) if it was able to find the file I'm specifying.